# Ajax and PHP Form Submit

Tags: php, ajax, forms, plugins, bootstrap-modal

I am using the malsup jquery form plugin to email a form via PHP, my form is in a bootstrap modal.

Everything seems to work fine, I receive success message however the email never shows up. It has something to do with my Ajax because the form works if I dont use AJAX, however, it then sends the user to the PHP url which is why i decided to use the plugin.

I have tried the ajaxForm and ajaxSubmit functions from malsup but with no success, the email just never shows up.

As a note, I am using another form (different name and id) and another AJAX and PHP call, but they work fine. They are completely separate files with different names, etc...

Plugin
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Live website (select Contact Me button)
http://www.sitesbymiller.com

HTML

```
 <form class="contactModalForm" id="contactModalForm" action="modalForm.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contactName">Name*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modalName" id="contactName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contactEmail">Email*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="modalEmail" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contactPhone">Phone</label>
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="modalPhone" id="contactPhone" placeholder="Enter Phone">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contactMessage">Message*</label>            
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="modalMessage" placeholder="Enter detailed message" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="modalSubmit" class="btn btn-success" id="modalSubmit" value="Submit"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modalClose" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</form>
```

Jquery/AJAX/JS file

```
var optionsB = {
        url:'modalForm.php',
        type:'post',
        clearForm:'true',
        resetForm:'true',
        cache:'false',
        success:    function() { 
            alert('Thanks for your message! I will get back to you shortly.'); 
        } 

};

// bind to the form's submit event 
$('#contactModalForm').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(optionsB); 
    return false; 
});
```

PHP modalForm.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['modalSubmit'])) {

if (!$_POST['modalName']) {
$error="<br />Please enter your name";
}
if (!$_POST['modalEmail']) {
$error.="<br />Please enter your email address";
}
if (!$_POST['modalMessage']) {
$error.="<br />Please enter a message";
}

if ($_POST['modalEmail']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['modalEmail'], 
FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";
}
if ($error) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) 
in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
} else {
            if (mail("sitesbymiller@gmail.com", "Message from website modal form!", "
                     Name: ".$_POST['modalName']."
                     Email: ".$_POST['modalEmail']."
                     Phone: ".$_POST['modalPhone']."
                     Message: ".$_POST['modalMessage']."
                     On/Off Switch: ".$_POST['onoffswitch']."
                     Current Website: ".$_POST['modalWebsite']."
                     Favorite Website: ".$_POST['modalFavorite']."
                     Website Features: ".$_POST['modalFeatures']."
                     Website Purpose: ".$_POST['modalPurpose'])) {   
                     $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank 
you!</strong> I\'ll be in touch.</div>';
                     } else {
                     $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was 
an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
                     }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: If your other AJAX/PHP form is working fine, and you are receiving success messages, could the issue be in the email code? Also, you should post your PHP.

Comment: @baum php code added. I didnt want to make the post a mile long but guess it only makes sense to post it! Thanks!

Comment: So you're seeing the "Thank you! I'll be in touch." message?

Comment: @baum exactly, but the email never comes. Form clears and all.

Comment: Check your spam? I've tried doing PHP `mail` in the past, and if your mail server isn't set up correctly, the messages will go to spam. In addition, if your system does not include the `sendmail` program or equivalent, make sure you have the SMTP server properly set up.

Comment: @baum Spam checked, nothing. I am using the same exact script on a form in the Contact section of the website and it works just fine. I don't know if its the modal causing an issue or the ajax.

Comment: @baum I fixed it. I think some of the options were causing issues in my AJAX and I had to use ajaxForm not ajaxSubmit. Thanks for helping me. I will post my code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and PHP files were good. Just had to make an adjustment to the JS/AJAX. I used the ajaxForm method instead of the ajaxSubmit and renamed my options variable as well as removed the url option, type option and cache option, and perfecto!

Big shoutout to http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started for creating such a great plugin that is user friendly and easy to use!

JS/AJAX

```
var options = {
        clearForm:'true',
        resetForm:'true',
        success:    function() { 
            alert('Thanks for your message! I will get back to you shortly.'); 
        } 

};

// pass options to ajaxForm 
$('#contactModalForm').ajaxForm(options);
```